# Windows reporting strange bugs hours after clean install

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

## What is Happening?

---

I am having problems with my Windows 10, even after a formatting and a clean install, the OS reports strange errors after a few hours, leaving the computer unusable.

All the problems happen after I try to open something as administrator, but hours ago was working perfectly. Other issues include the video driver being corrupted to the point where it can not open any accelerated graphics application.

The errors was:

- "Extended attributes are inconsistent."
- "Filesystem error (-1073740791)"

On the other post, people told me to do an extended hard-drive test, because my suspicions were that the hard drive was at the end of its life.
Meanwhile, the Linux I use (KDE Neon) did not show any recurring problems, only a random freeze during boot, forcing me to restart the computer.

My SMART output:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   187   151   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1625
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   054   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       46240
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   076   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       17634
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5235
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       227915
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       617
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       893650
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   101   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       46
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      10%     17633         -
# 2  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%     17629         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     17629         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17629         -
```

## What I've tried so far

---

I tried several times commands like `chkdsk /r`, `sfc /scannow` and none of them reported any problems, even after several runs.
The SMART Extended Test also reported no problems.

Comment: Please put the SMART output in the question.

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: Looks like the hard drive is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offered an explanation in an answer on your previous question and you deleted it. Apparently the answer wasn't clear enough.

1. chkdsk isn't guaranteed to be able to repair all previous file corruption, and sfc isn't guaranteed to be able to fix anything that might be bad with Windows.  However, chkdsk will ensure that there isn't a current hardware problem with the drive.  If chkdsk is showing no current problems with the drive, reformat the drive and reinstall Windows so that everything is sure to be complete and uncorrupted.
2. The reason problems are visible in Windows but not in Linux is likely because there is unrepaired file corruption, and it is in areas that Windows uses.  Linux files are not corrupted and Linux doesn't routinely access those areas, so it is unaffected.
3. The SMART output is indicating an old drive with some above-normal problem counts.  You don't want to ignore that.  It could still have some useful life left, but you need to keep your eye on it and be prepared to replace it.  Ensure that you keep your backups current.
4. Now that you've verified that there are not current hard errors on the drive, and after you reinstall Windows, you should not see new faults except possibly on very rare occasions.  If you very shortly start seeing new errors, it means that the drive is in the process of failing.  Use the time to offload your files while you still can.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your computer power supply unit or connections of data/power cable? In my experiences, a poor power supply to HDD causes many strange errors.

Comment: I've opened the computer and found nothing out of the norm, all the cables are secure and in place.

Comment: @BrennoFagundes, secure cables eliminates one potential cause, but that doesn't tell you if the PSU is delivering the proper power, and you couldn't tell that just by looking.  You would need to check the voltage.

Comment: Going to take a look with HWiNFO.